# CLISP - limited depth first search

Tags: search, common-lisp

trying to write code to do a limited depth first search on a given problem and limit.. im very new to this language so this is basicly just some thoughts.. dont bully me xD

```
(defstruct state 
   pos 
   vel
   action
   cost
   track
   other)

(defstruct problem 
   initial-state
   fn-nextStates 
   fn-isGoal 
    fn-h);heuristic funtion

(defstruct node
  parent
  state)

(defun limdepthfirstsearch (problem limit)
  (return (recursiveldfs make-node(problem-initial-state) problem limit )))

(defun recursiveldfs (node problem limit)
  (if (problem-fn-isGoal (node-state node)) (solution(node)))
  (if (= limit 0) ':corte)

  (setf (cutoff_ocurred) nil)

  (loop for each (possible-actions) in (problem-fn-nextstates(node-state node)) do
    (setf (child) (nextState (node-state node) (possible-actions)))
    (setf (result) (recursiveldfs child problem (- limit 1)))
    (if (= result ':corte) (setf (cutoff_ocurred) t))
    (if (!= result nil) (return result))
  )
  (if (= cutoff_ocurred t) '(:corte))
  (if (= cutoff_ocurred nil) nil)
)
```

Comment: Hi @xicocana!   Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.   Users here will typically want to see a clear question with a clear possible solution before trying to help...  (ie.  what did you run, including test data?  what did you observe?   what did you expect to observe?  what have you tried to resolve the problem?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second @BadZen's comment, but it seems you are quite new to common lisp, so I'll just give some pointers or comments to your code.

First of all, do consider following an introduction to common-lisp, for example: [Practical common lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) for getting started quickly, or even better (though based on scheme) [the SICP lectures](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/classes/6.001/abelson-sussman-lectures/), for a deeper understanding of lisp.

Also please submit code that at least compiles, or ask a question about the error messages you get. Your code does not compile. And please try to use the common-lisp standard style a bit, at least separate multiple words in names by "-". Your code is hard to read.

To your code:

1. In `limdepthfirstsearch`, `return` is unnecessary. In common-lisp `return` is used only to return a value and exit from a nil-named block, for example a loop, or dolist, etc.
2. In the same function, `make-node(problem-initial-state)` has wrong syntax (this is not how lisp functions take arguments), and besides, `make-node` needs two arguments (parent and state). What you probably want is:
   `(recursiveldfs (make-node NIL (problem-initial-state problem)) problem limit)` where `NIL` I assume is the initial problem parent (whatever that means in your structures). If `(problem-initial-state problem)` is in fact a list `'(parent state)`then you need to write `(recursiveldfs (apply #'make-node (problem-initial-state problem)) problem limit)`
3. In the definition of `recursiveldfs`, the statement `(problem-fn-isGoal (node-state node)` implies that `(node-state node)` returns a `problem` structure. In the same line, `(solution(node))` is syntactically wrong, there is no function called `solution` in your code, and `node` is not a function either. And a space is missing between `solution` and `(node)`. I can't figure out what is meant here.
4. Again in the definition of `recursiveldfs`, you write `(setf (cutoff_ocurred) nil)`. Since there is no function called `cutoff_ocurred`, I presume you mean `(setf cutoff_ocurred nil)`, but still, there is no variable called `cutoff_ocurred`. What is meant here? Perhaps you need to start `recursiveldfs` with a `(let ((cutoff_ocurred nil)) ..)` instead?
5. In the loop below, drop the parens from `(possible-actions)` (two occurrences). A variable over which the loop happens is needed here.
6. `(probem-fn-nextstates(node-state node))` is missing a space after `problem-fn-nextstates`, and again, as in (3), it implies that `(node-state node)` returns a `problem` structure. `do` goes in the next line (look up some common lisp style guides).
7. After `do`, only the first statement belongs to `do`, the rest is syntactically wrong. If you need to `do` several statements in a loop use `do (progn (...) (...) ... (...))`.
8. `child` and `result` are neither defined functions nor defined variables (see 4).
9. What is `:corte`?

Please rewrite your code with these comments in mind, and after taking an introduction to common lisp (at least a couple of chapters from the gigamonkeys book), and edit your question or submit a new one, with code that compiles, and with example input, as @BadZen suggests. I also suggest type annotating your structures, either using :type or with a comment.